# Function not found in module

Tags: javascript, module

Suppost you have a module file like this:

**authService.js**

```js
import { Screen } from 'quasar'
import * as authPopup from 'src/services/auth/authPopup'
import * as authRedirect from 'src/services/auth/authRedirect'

const loginMethod = Screen.lt.sm ? 'redirect' : 'popup'

export const auth = (loginMethod === 'popup')
  ? { loginMethod, authPopup }
  : { loginMethod, authRedirect }
```

If would be great if it could be consumed like this:

**consumer.js**

```js
import { auth } from 'src/services/auth/authService'

const getProfile = () => {
  if (!auth.getAccount()) { return Promise.reject(new Error('no logged on user')) }

  console.log('loginMethod ', auth.loginMethod)
}
```

But it errors out saying that `auth.getAccount()` is not a function. Why is that? We're clearly exporting the `auth` with all functions and the string in the `authService.js` file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And those objects are the only thing exported. How is it that you expect a `getAccount` method to be available? *edited* - the comment about the syntax error was incorrect.

Comment: The `getAccount` function is in the file `authPopup.js` and `authRedirect.js`. Sorry, I'm new at this and trying to find my way.

Comment: Ah, well you should be able to get to `auth.authPopup.getAccount` then. Of course you have to check which version of the object you get first. Or you could explicitly pull the `getAccount` method out of those objects, though that may or may not work properly depending on the implementation.

Comment: That's not the goal, I would like to be able to get to it using the syntax in the example above `auth.LoginMethod` and `auth.getAccount()`

Comment: You'll have to arrange for that explicitly in the `authService` file somehow. As it is, your exporting an object with two properties, one called "loginMethod" and the other called either "authPopup" or "authRedirect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant to do

```
export const auth = (loginMethod === 'popup')
  ? { loginMethod, ...authPopup }
  : { loginMethod, ...authRedirect };
```

so that the exported `auth` object actually will contain all the methods from the respective imported namespace object, not a `.authPopup` or `.authRedirect` property. Or alternatively, more explicitly, you can write:

```
export const auth = { loginMethod: Screen.lt.sm ? 'redirect' : 'popup' };
Object.assign(auth, auth.loginMethod === 'popup' ? authPopup : authRedirect);
```

Comment: I undestand what you're saying but the `getAccount()` method is in the file `authPopup .js` and `authRedirect.js`. It would be great if it was accessible like `auht.getAccount()` together with `auth.loginMethod`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Is using the spread operator less preferred?  It looks cleaner and has no disadvantage in this case I assume.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure what exactly the two modules were exporting at first. Edited to something different now.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Nah, the object spread is fine, however your two object literals are a bit repetitive. Also with `Object.assign` it's clearer how this is different from your original code - for those people who are not familar with spread syntax.